# Problems with bib and aux files, and References not showing up in TeXShop

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, errors

I'm just started using TeXShop on a OS X Yosemite, and this is getting very, very frustrating.I'm trying to put reference in my text, but when I compile to pdf there is just "references"and an empty page bellow that. Furthermore, when I compile the bib file with bibTex i get this message:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017)
The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file test.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file test.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

the bib file is the following:

```
@book{netto1980semiotica,
Author = {Netto, J Teixeira Coelho},
Date-Added = {2017-06-25 06:05:05 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2017-06-25 06:05:05 +0000},
Publisher = {Editora Perspectiva},
Title = {Semi{\'o}tica, informa{\c{c}}{\~a}o e comunica{\c{c}}{\~a}o: diagrama da teoria do signo},
Volume = {168},
Year = {1980}}

@book{charaudeau2006discurso,
Author = {Charaudeau, Patrick},
Date-Added = {2017-06-25 06:05:04 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2017-06-25 06:05:04 +0000},
Publisher = {Contexto S{\~a}o Paulo},
Title = {Discurso das m{\'\i}dias},
Year = {2006}}

@book{pignatari2003informaccao,
Author = {Pignatari, D{\'e}cio},
Date-Added = {2017-06-25 06:05:02 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2017-06-25 06:05:02 +0000},
Publisher = {Ateli{\^e} Editorial},
Title = {Informa{\c{c}}{\~a}o. Linguagem. Comunica{\c{c}}{\~a}o},
Year = {2003}}
```

I tried everything i found online, nothing worked

This is the text, it's part from a example i downloaded, hence all the anotations:

```
\documentclass[
% -- opções da classe memoir --
12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
openright,          % capítulos começam em pág ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)
twoside,            % para impressão em recto e verso. Oposto a oneside
a4paper,            % tamanho do papel. 
% -- opções da classe abntex2 --
%chapter=TITLE,     % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
%section=TITLE,     % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
%subsection=TITLE,  % títulos de subseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
%subsubsection=TITLE,% títulos de subsubseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
% -- opções do pacote babel --
english,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
french,             % idioma adicional para hifenização
spanish,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
brazil,             % o último idioma é o principal do documento
]{abntex2}


\usepackage{lmodern}            % Usa a fonte Latin Modern
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Selecao de codigos de fonte.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Codificacao do documento (conversão automática dos acentos)
\usepackage{indentfirst}        % Indenta o primeiro parágrafo de cada seção.
\usepackage{color}              % Controle das cores
\usepackage{graphicx}           % Inclusão de gráficos
\usepackage{microtype}          % para melhorias de justificação


% Pacotes adicionais, usados no anexo do modelo de folha de identificação
% ---
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
% ---

% ---
% Pacotes adicionais, usados apenas no âmbito do Modelo Canônico do     abnteX2
% ---
\usepackage{lipsum}             % para geração de dummy text
% ---

% ---
% Pacotes de citações
% ---
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}     % Paginas com as                     citações na bibl
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}   % Citações padrão ABNT

% --- 
% CONFIGURAÇÕES DE PACOTES
% --- 

% ---
% Configurações do pacote backref
% Usado sem a opção hyperpageref de backref
\renewcommand{\backrefpagesname}{Citado na(s) página(s):~}
% Texto padrão antes do número das páginas
\renewcommand{\backref}{}
% Define os textos da citação
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
    \ifcase #1 %
    Nenhuma citação no texto.%
\or
    Citado na página #2.%
\else
    Citado #1 vezes nas páginas #2.%
\fi}%
% ---

% ---
% Informações de dados para CAPA e FOLHA DE ROSTO
% ---
\titulo{Edwards Deming e Armand V. Feigenbaum}
\autor{Marcos Silva Laydner}
\local{Brasil}
\data{2017, 24 de junho}
\instituicao{%
  Unisul
  \par
  Curso de Administração Matutino
  \par
  }
\tipotrabalho{Relatório técnico}
% O preambulo deve conter o tipo do trabalho, o objetivo, 
% o nome da instituição e a área de concentração 
\preambulo{}
% ---

% ---
% Configurações de aparência do PDF final

% alterando o aspecto da cor azul
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{41,5,195}

% informações do PDF
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
    %pagebackref=true,
    pdftitle={\@title}, 
    pdfauthor={\@author},
    pdfsubject={\imprimirpreambulo},
    pdfcreator={LaTeX with abnTeX2},
    pdfkeywords={abnt}{latex}{abntex}{abntex2}{relatório técnico}, 
    colorlinks=true,            % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=blue,             % color of internal links
    citecolor=blue,             % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,              % color of file links
    urlcolor=blue,
    bookmarksdepth=4
}
\makeatother
% --- 

% --- 
% Espaçamentos entre linhas e parágrafos 
% --- 

% O tamanho do parágrafo é dado por:
\setlength{\parindent}{1.3cm}

% Controle do espaçamento entre um parágrafo e outro:
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}  % tente também \onelineskip

% ---
% compila o indice
% ---
\makeindex
% ---

% ----
% Início do documento
% ----
\begin{document}
% Seleciona o idioma do documento (conforme pacotes do babel)            
 %\selectlanguage{english}
\selectlanguage{brazil}

% Retira espaço extra obsoleto entre as frases.
\frenchspacing
```

the thing goes on util it reaches the bibliography now I've added \nocite{*} to it

```
\phantompart

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Referências}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{test}

\phantompart

\end{document}
```

and the result is this:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017)
The top-level auxiliary file: Trabalho Teoria das Organizações.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file Trabalho Teoria     das Organizações.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Trabalho Teoria das Organizações.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Trabalho Teoria das Organizações.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How does your TeX file look like? Have you run (pdf)latex on it before running bibtex?

Comment: Yes, i have run the:  latex - bibtex - latex - latex , no good

Comment: Please have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number. There it is explained what to run in which order.

Comment: Do you depend on using `abntex`? The class is a mess.

Comment: Yeah, I do, is the oficial regulation of Brazil and every student's nightmare.

Comment: @Johannes_B, yes, the class is a mess. Using `memoir` to replicate Word-as-typewriter-typography _and_ wishing something could be improved and infinitely tinkered is naive at best.

Comment: @Marcos, it is the "official" norm "as-interpreted-by-your-institution" (universities aren't obliged to enforce them, and in practice interpret them freely). And it's not a nightmare. The nightmare is having your supervisor/clerk/library worker/committee nag about it and insist that it's "science" or "the way things are at academia".

Answer (score 2):

\nocite{*}

**Does not work with abntex2**. According to `ABNT` rules, you "cannot" use `\nocite` (that is, bibliography = references; no citation in text = no references).

A **real** MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{abntex2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}

\begin{document}
\cite{netto1980semiotica}

\cite{pignatari2003informaccao}

\cite{charaudeau2006discurso}.

\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

Which works fine.

Either move on to `biblatex-abnt` or use another style -- do not use `abntex2-cite` (which won't be upgraded and has scant support).

`biblatex` example:

```
\documentclass{abntex2}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=abnt,
%ittitles,
indent,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % if you’re using biblatex
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@book{netto1980semiotica,
    Author = {Netto, J Teixeira Coelho},
    Date-Added = {2017-06-25 06:05:05 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-06-25 06:05:05 +0000},
    Publisher = {Editora Perspectiva},
    Title = {Semi{\'o}tica, informa{\c{c}}{\~a}o e comunica{\c{c}}{\~a}o: diagrama da teoria do signo},
    Volume = {168},
    Year = {1980}}

@book{charaudeau2006discurso,
    Author = {Charaudeau, Patrick},
    Date-Added = {2017-06-25 06:05:04 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-06-25 06:05:04 +0000},
    Publisher = {Contexto São Paulo},
    Title = {Discurso das mídias},
    Year = {2006}}

@book{pignatari2003informaccao,
    Author = {Pignatari, Décio},
    Date-Added = {2017-06-25 06:05:02 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-06-25 06:05:02 +0000},
    Publisher = {Ateliê Editorial},
    Title = {Informação. Linguagem. Comunicação,
    Year = {2003}}



\end{filecontents*}




\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Another crucial benefit from using `biblatex-abnt` is that you need not worry about accents -- just try it out, which is easier: `Informa{\c{c}}{\~a}o` or `Informação`? Typing Latin accents "the TeX way" is boring, useless, and old-fashioned after `utf8`.